# Sharing pdf to Evernote not working in Android

Tags: android, evernote

I am creating a pdf for sharing by passing this intent to `createChooser()`:

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
            .setType("image/*")
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToPdf);
            .getIntent()
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

This is working for mail, dropbox and other apps but for some reason it shows up with the file ending `.null` in Evernote, the file size is correct though.

How can I upload the pdf to Evernote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is the asterisk in your file type - that's not a supported MIME type in Evernote.  Supported types for Resources are [listed in the Evernote API documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/resources.php#types):

```
image/gif
image/jpeg
image/png
audio/wav
audio/mpeg
audio/amr
application/pdf
```